# ExceptionHandler fails to handle exceptions in AuthenticationManager

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, exception, spring-security

I'm building a rest api server with spring boot and I'm using jdbcTemplate as API key validation for requests. Next is the implementation class that inherited the Authentication Manager that I defined.

```
@Component
public class ApiKeyAuthManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public ApiKeyAuthManager(DataSource dataSource){
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException,CannotGetJdbcConnectionException {
        String principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();


        try {
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM apikey WHERE key = ? AND to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') < exprt_date AND exprt_yn != 'Y'";

            int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, Integer.class, principal);

            if(count > 0){
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
            }else{
                throw new BadCredentialsException("");
            };
        } catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

Next, a class code that implements an Authentication EntryPoint interface to handle responses to authentication failures.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        logger.error("message", authException);

        ApiErrorResponse responseBody = new ApiErrorResponse(ApiResponseConstants.STATUS_ERROR, ApiResponseConstants.MESSAGE_API_ACCESS_DENIED, null);

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseBody));
    }
}
```

Next, the handler code for creating and returning custom responses for each exception.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomGlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(CannotGetJdbcConnectionException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleCannotGetJdbcConnectionException(CannotGetJdbcConnectionException exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(400).body(new ApiErrorResponse(ApiResponseConstants.STATUS_FAIL, exception.getMessage(), null));
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the DefaultErrorAttributes class for customizing basic response types for non-exception errors.

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomErrorAttributes.class);

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {

        Map<String, Object> result = super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, options.excluding(ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.STACK_TRACE));

        Exception ex = (Exception) webRequest.getAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.EXCEPTION",0);
        logger.error("message", ex);

        Map<String, Object> resultBody = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        resultBody.put("status", ApiResponseConstants.STATUS_ERROR);
        resultBody.put("message", result.get("message"));
        resultBody.put("detail", null);

        return resultBody;
    }
}
```

I registered the above settings in the spring security config.

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityfilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    apiKeyAuthFilter.setAuthenticationManager(new ApiKeyAuthManager(dataSource));

    http.antMatcher("/api/**")
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .addFilter(apiKeyAuthFilter).authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAutehticationEntryPoint);

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginprocess")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login?auth=fail")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();

    return http.build();
}
```

I wanted to let you know that DB connection is the cause of DB connection by error message about rest request when DB is disconnected or wrong connection is established. So, I deliberately intended to make connection error by setting JDBC connection information of application.properties differently, and I was able to catch CannotGetJdbcConnectionException as expected.

I expected this Exception to be handled by one handler and create a custom response. However, none of the handlers (ExceptionHandler, DefaultErrorAttributes, etc.) handled the exception, and the server returned the login page html in response.

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7TPD.png)

Perhaps my prediction is that due to the setting of the level or level of handling exceptions in Spring, the exception was propagated to the servlet stage and returned the login page due to authority for reasons such as conflict with the spring security setting, etc.

How can we resolve this situation?
How to return an Exception that occurred in jdbcTemplate as a custom response to user requests? How can I control this exception?